# Why I am not able to use a DescendingIterator on a Linked List?

Tags: java, android, linked-list

I have the following snippet of code, which is responsible reading a **`JSON`** file and creating a Doubly linked list. I am following the linked list `API` from the official source [**LinkedList**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator())

```
public void createVerticies() {
        try {

            List<Vertex> doublyLinkedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Vertex>());

            JSONObject jsonObject = new AssetsFileReader().readJsonInput(context, "data/stations_0.1.json");
            JSONArray statArr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("stations_array");
            for (int i = 0; i < statArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = statArr.getJSONObject(i);
                Vertex vertex = new Vertex();
                vertex.setName(jObj.optString("name"));
                vertex.setId(jObj.optInt("vertexId"));
                vertex.setLat(jObj.optString("lat"));
                vertex.setLng(jObj.optString("lng"));
                vertex.setFunctional(jObj.optBoolean("isFunctional"));
                vertex.setEndTerminal(jObj.optBoolean("isEndTerminal"));
                vertex.setVertPrev(jObj.optInt("vertPrev"));
                vertex.setVertNext(jObj.optInt("vertNext"));

                doublyLinkedList.add(vertex.getId() - 1, vertex);

            }


            ListIterator<Vertex> listIterator = doublyLinkedList.listIterator();
            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(listIterator.next().getName());
            }

            ListIterator<Vertex> desListIt = doublyLinkedList.descendingIterator // Problem 


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However the **IDE** does not allow me to use a descending iterator here:

```
 ListIterator<Vertex> desListIt = doublyLinkedList.descendingIterator // Problem
```

Am I missing something the way I am creating the **`linkedlist`**?

[image]

Comment: i don't know if its the issue but there's a semicolon `;` missing at the end of that line.

Comment: @Ivan I know that, however I did not include that because the method is not recognized, not a problem with code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkedList` has a `descendingIterator`, but `Collections.synchronizedList` returns a `List` implementation that doesn't have that method.

Since you are wrapping your `LinkedList` instance with a `Collections.synchronizedList`, you no longer have direct access to the `LinkedList` instance, and you can't execute `LinkedList` specific methods.

Therefore you can't call `descendingIterator`.

That said, I'm not sure why you are using `Collections.synchronizedList`, since your `List` doesn't seem to be shared by multiple threads.

Therefore, perhaps you can simply change

```
List<Vertex> doublyLinkedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Vertex>());
```

to

```
LinkedList<Vertex> doublyLinkedList new LinkedList<Vertex>();
```

Comment: So essentially when I use a Synch List I am not using a Linked List? However even after changing to  `List<Vertex> doublyLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();` I cant see the descending iterator.

Comment: Its not working, please refer to the fresh edit to my question, I have added a picture.

Comment: @User3 That's because you only see methods of the `List` interface (since that's the compile time type of your variable). You can overcome that by changing the variable type to `LinkedList<Vertex>`.

Comment: I did that. Please refer to the edit in my question!

Comment: @User3 Note that I suggested you change to `LinkedList<Vertex> doublyLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();`, not `List<Vertex> doublyLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: Dammnn! I missed the intial Data type to the left! Thanks it works now!!